# How to use json-ld.net to create JSON-LD structured data - code example

Tags: c#, json-ld

There is currently no documentation, tests, code examples, or anything at all on the web to show how to use the json-ld.net library to create JSON-LD structured data, despite it being listed as the official C# library on https://json-ld.org/ and downloaded on nuget alot. (The authors don't seem to want to add any, which is weird.) Specifically, I want to create a JobPosting: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#example. The repository doesn't seem to have anything in it related to Jobs so I'm assuming we have to create our own POCOs by hand, but I'm not sure.